# How to detect if an object has been moved on the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm implementing Manipulation events to check for movement of objects (triangle, square, parallelogram) following the tutorial here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee649090(v=vs.100).aspx

However, I'm working with objects I've created myself and the **RenderTransform doesn't seem to work with that**.

*Error I get: does not contain a definition for 'RenderTransform' and no extension method 'RenderTransform' accepting a first argument of type Tangible could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

How can I make it work? Do I need to implement my own RenderTransform method? But I don't see why it won't just work with my own objects.

I have tried to use polygons instead of my own objects, however that doesn't solve the problem and instead gives null pointer exceptions since the objects on my screen are actually 'Tangible' type objects.

My code:

```
private void PlayingCanvas_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Tangible polyToMove = e.OriginalSource as Tangible;

        Matrix polysMatrix = ((MatrixTransform)polyToMove.RenderTransform).Matrix; 

        polysMatrix.RotateAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation,
                                 e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                                 e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

        polysMatrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X,
                                  e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);

        polyToMove.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(polysMatrix);
}
```

Comment: What does your object inherit from? The `RenderTransform` property is defined on the `UIElement` type, so it has to inherit from that or its subclass (which is pretty much any control class).

Comment: It inherits from the Polygon class from Windows.Shapes. However, when I try and get polygons as the OriginalSource, it throws null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Are you really sure it inherits `System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon`? That class is sealed and you cannot derive from it.